# casting using llvm::dyn_cast causing in error

Tags: llvm

I'm trying to iterate over uses of operand of store inst. I follow the programmer's manual to do this but I get error.

```
//x is store instruction pointing to [store i32 5, i32* %a, align 4]
Value *op2 = x->getOperand(1);
for (Value::use_iterator useItr=op2->use_begin(),useEnd=op2->use_end(); useItr!=useEnd;useItr++){
    if (Instruction *Inst = dyn_cast_or_null<Instruction>(*useItr))
        errs()<<"done";
}
```

I get this error message:

IR/Use.h:204: UserTy *llvm::value_use_iterator::operator*() const [UserTy = llvm::User]: Assertion `U && "Cannot dereference end iterator!"' failed.

In my understanding, If casting is not possible dyn_cast should return a null pointer not an error. I also tried dyn_cast_or_null, but same error.

Comment: Is there some other way I can get it done?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem seems to be with latest llvm code as I used the svn checkout for latest code. I finally took 3.4 stable release and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is from dereferencing `useItr`, not from the `dyn_cast`. Your code looks fine to me, so I took a look at the implementation of `value_use_iterator`, and the only way I can think of for your error to occur is if one of the value's uses is `NULL`.

A use of `NULL` is not something that can occur in a legal module, though. So I recommend running the [verifier pass](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#verify-module-verifier) on your module before your code to see if it can spot the problem - otherwise you'll have to carefully examine the module yourself.